# requests are not being forwarded from serveo.net host to my localhost

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to make a local server for dialogflow bot. I have written a sample code which handles a specific intent in the bot a.d to achieve this I I have used serveo.net as the tunneling software and node.js to build my server. The request coming from dialogflow reaches the serveo.net but isn't forwarded to my localhost and I am not able to produce a response.

I have tried running node and serveo.net in two simultaneous command prompts but it still doesn't work.

```
app.post('/webhook',express.json(),(request,response) => {
    console.log("Server Hit");
    webhookprocessing(request,respond);
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
intentMap.set("webhook",webhookprocessing);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

This code is a snippet of the post method defined .

[image]

[image]

webhook url on dialogflow:

edit2: I tried to check the webhook url which I mentioned in dialogflow webhook , I saw this in the url page
[image]

edit3: After sometime I saw this result on my console
   [image]

The fulfillment request I got is this:

```
{
  "responseId": "171a0d20-f2f7-4743-a11f-3489a3f66a8e-273dd5df",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "My name is karthik",
    "action": "webhook",
    "parameters": {
      "given-name": "Karthik"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/master-bot-53dee/agent/intents/15b96d92-4adb-4657-8b15-ebdf7df180b4",
      "displayName": "webhook"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "payload": {}
  },
  "session": "projects/master-bot-53dee/agent/sessions/eb40aee2-46d0-eefa-fc21-77c273e5a9eb"
}
```

I am sorry for my bad presentation I new to this and  using node.js.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There isn't quite enough information in your question to help us help you. The output from ngrok isn't showing any calls at all, so it isn't clear what error, if any, is being generated. It may also help if you updated the question with the request and response that are in the activity console that you can see at http://localhost:4040/ by default. It may also help to show a screen shot from the dialogflow fulfillment tab, to show what you have the fulfillment URL set to.

Comment: ngrok wasn't working so I had to shift to serveo.net and I have updated the picture for webhook url on dialogflow.